# gcc not picking up kernel header files

Tags: gcc

I am trying to compile a program gcc throws `fatal error: asm/page.h: No such file or directory` page.h exists. How would i setup gcc to include a path. I went a bit nuts and typed `apt-get install linux-headers*` Here are the results `find / -name page.h`

`/usr/src/linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-amd64/include/config/hugetlb/page.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-common/include/asm-generic/page.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-common/include/xen/page.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-common/arch/x86/include/asm/xen/page.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-common/arch/x86/include/asm/page.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.18.0-kali1-common/include/asm-generic/page.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.18.0-kali1-common/include/xen/page.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.18.0-kali1-common/arch/x86/include/asm/xen/page.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.18.0-kali1-common/arch/x86/include/asm/page.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.18.0-kali1-amd64/include/config/hugetlb/page.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At execution time you can include a header file using the -I argument...

```
gcc myCProgram.c -o myCProgram -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.18.0-kali1-common/include/asm-generic/
```

Check an example here

http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-i.htm

and the documentation (RTFM)

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Directory-Options.html